# sonarqube: Is try-with-resources or close this "ObjectInputStream" in a "finally" clause for this code false positive?

Tags: java, sonarqube, try-with-resources

For the below java code though resource is closed in a finally block sonar is reporting:Use try-with-resources or close this “ObjectInputStream” in a “finally” clause.

```java
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(value);
    objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)
}
finally {
        try 
            {
            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                fileInputStream.close();
            }
            if (objIn != null) {
                objIn.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
```

Sonar doesn't report above issue   when  try-with-resources is used , since the version of java i use doesn't support  try-with-resource i had to go with closing resource in a finally block.

Comment: *"...since the version of java i use doesn't support try-with-resource"* — Try-with-resources was introduced in Java 7. Are you saying that you are using a Java version lower than 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a false positive.

If `fileInputStream.close()` throws an exception, `objIn.close()` will not be called and the `ObjectInputStream` will not be closed.

You should separate the two `close` calls to make sure both streams are closed:

```
finally {
    try {
        if (fileInputStream != null) {
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {}

    try {
        if (objIn != null) {
            objIn.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {}
}
```

Comment: what's confusing is the sonar sometimes concludes that resources are closed even though they are implemented in the same fashion as in the question

Comment: @Billi: it's definitely possible that sonar is just wrong about it for some reason, but I would very closely inspect the differences between the cases  where it does and it doesn't complain. I very much doubt that it's **exactly** the same code (checked by the same sonar configuration).

Comment: @Billi By the way, I just thought of something. Since `objIn` uses `fileInputStream`, you should probably close `objIn` _first_.

Comment: @rickdenhaan would the order matter since the finally block will be executed only after try is executed

Comment: @Billi *Hypothetically*, depending on the exact implementations in the InputStreams, there could *theoretically* be a case of: `fileInputStream.close()` -> `IOException` because the stream is in use by `objIn` but that exception is ignored -> `objIn.close()` -> no exception, `fileInputStream` is now no longer in use but it will also not be closed since `fileInputStream.close()` will not be executed again. It is more likely that the *actual* process will be the other way around: `fileInputStream.close()` -> fine -> `objIn.close()` -> `IOException` because `fileInputStream` is already closed.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` is *in* the `try` when in reality it has to be outside.

```java
try {
  fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(value);
  objIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)
} finally {
  try {
    if (fileInputStream != null){
      fileInputStream.close();
    }
    if (objIn != null){
      objIn.close();
    }
  } catch (IOException ignored) {}
}
```

Although I'm not sure if SonarQube will understand that you closed it.